# How to get value of a select2 from datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get value of a select2 from a datatable and store it into variable.Actually I have appended three rows using for loop and so there are three select2 in three rows.I want get values from that three select2 and store it into variables.
I have tried many ways to get the values from that select2.When I m appending one row then the value is get from that select2 and stored in a variables.
I have used

```
var mno_id = $("#mno_idselected :selected").val();
```

The above code is working for getting  the value from one select2 when I m appending one row.
But When I m appending more than one row,I m unable to get the value from a particular select2.

Comment: Could you please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate select2 after dataTables is initialised. You can do that in the drawCallback callback.

Do not use id's to reference the select2's. I guess you will have a lot of select2's on multiple pages, so give them a dummy class like dt-select2 so you can initialise all visible select2's in one call. But by all mean preserve the id's for reference in event handlers.

```
$('#example').DataTable({
  ...
  drawCallback: function() {
     $('.dt-select2').select2();
  }
})
```

demo -> http://jsfiddle.net/u91javfy/

See this example include a select option on a header to filter the data: http://jsfiddle.net/73zawd5b/5/#&togetherjs=fgu5BihnA7

```
$('#example').DataTable({
  initComplete: function() {
    this.api().columns('.fName').every(function() {
      var column = this;
      var select = $('<select class="f"><option value="">First Name</option></select>')
        .appendTo($(column.header()).empty())
        .on('change', function() {
          var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
            $(this).val()
          );

          column
            .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
            .draw();
        });

      column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
        select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
      });
    });
    this.api().columns('.lName').every(function() {
      var column = this;
      var select = $('<select class="f"><option value="">Last Name</option></select>')
        .appendTo($(column.header()).empty())
        .on('change', function() {
          var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
            $(this).val()
          );

          column
            .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
            .draw();
        });

      column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
        select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
      });
    });
  }


})
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.f').select2();
});
```

Comment: I have initialised it but now alsoi m not getting the value of that particular select2.

Comment: The solution which you provide is also proper but i m unable to get the value from that select2.